# Automatically send TFS WorkItems to MS Project Server (Work Item Workflow)

Tags: tfs-workitem, project-server

I have Microsoft Project Server 2013 integrated with a TFS 2012 instance. I have the ability to create work items from project and tfs and it will sync back and forth.

What I'm trying to do is have certain work item types automatically submit to project server. Below is what I have found elsewhere, and it almost works (Submit is yes) but the ProjectName field is showing up blank.

I get the errors: "Field 'Project Server Enterprise Project' cannot be empty and Field 'Project Server Sync Requested Project GUID' cannot be empty.

Does anyone know how I can find what TFS expects for these values?

```
<TRANSITION from="" to="To Do">
          <REASONS>
            <DEFAULTREASON value="New task" />
          </REASONS>
          <FIELDS>
          <FIELD refname="Microsoft.Sync.ProjSrv.Submit">
               <COPY from="value" value="Yes" />
             </FIELD>
          <FIELD refname="Microsoft.Sync.ProjSrv.ProjectName">
             <COPY from="value" value="PROJECT_SERVER_PROJECT_NAME" />
           </FIELD>
        </FIELDS>
        </TRANSITION>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the values you're after are;

- 'Project Server Sync Requested Project GUID' = Microsoft.Sync.ProjSrv.RequestedProjGuid
- 'Project Server Enterprise Project' = Microsoft.Sync.ProjSrv.ProjectName

Is your team project mapped to a single project plan? If so Microsoft.Sync.ProjSrv.ProjectName will be readonly, you only need to specify it if it is mapped to multiple project plans.

Comment: Yes, I'm mapped to a single project. I'll try setting the GUID instead of the name. However, I need to know what values to put in the TRANSITION xml to make it actually work, or at least know how to find them. How would I find the RequestedProjGuid for the project?

Comment: I'm in the early stages of attempting to do the same thing as soon as project server here set up, should be within the next few days. So far I have just been researching how to go about it. As soon as I get the chance to try for myself I'll give you an update. I may end up directing a question back in your direction :P.